# I want to pass a datatable to wcf service using angularjs

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, wcf

Here is my wcf service which has used the datatable request:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/checkout",
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            void Checkout(UserDetails data);
```

This is my client side code:

```
    $scope.checkout = function () {
            var data = {
                "MemberID": "2500394300",
                "CategoryID": "1",
                "ProductID": "1",
                "PointValue": "100"
            };
            $http.post(
                "url",
                data,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }
            ).success(function (result) {

                alert(result);
            });

        }
```

Comment: You should work with json data for easy consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the `data` variable to a JSON string:

```
$http.post(
    "url",
    JSON.stringify(data)
```